# Next command behavior on pattern space

Tags: sed

Suppose below `sed` command:

```
$ seq 4 | sed 'p;n;'
1
1
2
3
3
4
```

I couldn't understand why `2` and `4` are printed once while

> The "n" command will print out the current pattern space...

and `p;` prints current pattern space earlier than `n;`.

Let me show you my thoughts (`O`: output, `PS`: pattern space):

```
 +------------+---------+-----------+
 | Current PS |   `p;`  |    `n;`   |
 +------------+---------+-----------+
 |     1      |   O=1   | O=1  PS=2 |
 +------------+---------+-----------+
 |     2      |   O=2   | O=2  PS=3 |
 +------------+---------+-----------+
 |     3      |   O=3   | O=3  PS=4 |
 +------------+---------+-----------+
 |     4      |   O=4   | O=4  PS=4 |
 +------------+---------+-----------+
```

What am I missing in definition of `n` here that I expect `2` and `4` to be output twice as well?

Comment: Where does the quote come from? I can't find it in the manual page of sed (neither gnu nor posix).

Comment: @choroba the quote is from http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51 and also I can read it from https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens:

`1` is read into PS.

`p` : `1` is printed.

`n` : `1` is printed again, `2` is read into PS.

End of iteration, `2` is printed.

`3` is read into PS.

`p` : `3` is printed.

etc.

Modify the string to see why it's being printed:

```
$ seq 4 | sed 'p;s/$/ n command/;n;s/$/ end/'
1
1 n command
2 end
3
3 n command
4 end
```

Comment: Thank you. I see I missed two points. End of iteration and updating PS following it.